# Run `check` task without running `test` task in Gradle

Tags: gradle

How do I check my source code without running any of my unit tests? `gradle check` doesn't do anything after I remove its `test` dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by "check my source code"? What do you expect the check task to do and why?

Comment: I'd like to run syntax and type checking when I run `gradle check`, and not run unit tests or integration tests until I use `gradle build`

Comment: either you can run `gradle clean build -x test` or `gradle clean assemble`

Answer (score 1):

`./gradlew check -x test` is the command you're looking for.

`check` may do nothing, because there are no other checks, like linting or static code analysis. It may be the case that tests were the only registered check that you've skipped.